# List of unique items in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this: `mylist = [(1,2,3),(6,1,1),(7,8,1),(3,4,5)]`. If I use the list comprehension `slist = [item for sublist in mylist for item in sublist]`, I could get `slist = [1,2,3,6,1,1,7,8,1,3,4,5]`.

How should I modify if I need only unique elements in `slist` like this `[1,2,3,6,7,8,4,5]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually make your first part a bit easier by using [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and then passing the result to [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), which will only retain the unique elements:

```
>>> mylist = [(1,2,3),(6,1,1),(7,8,1),(3,4,5)]
>>> import itertools
>>> set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 11):

Use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of a list.

```
set(slist)
```

If you *really* need it as a list then you can convert it back to a list:

```
slist = list(set(slist))
```

Note that this conversion won't preserve the original order of the elements. If you need the same order you can use this instead:

```
>>> result = []
>>> seen = set()
>>> for innerlist in mylist:
        for item in innerlist:
            if not item in seen:
                seen.add(item)
                result.append(item)
>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]
```

Comment: May I ask a question here? What is the complexity of this operation `item in seen` (look up in `set` object)? Is it as effective as looking up in `dict` object?

Comment: @ovgolovin: Yes, it should be about as fast as dict.

Comment: Here it is. http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity The complexities look the same, but for `set` they used the `Worst Case` term, and for `dict` they used the `Amortized Worst Case` term. I wonder why.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
chain = itertools.chain(*mylist)
print(set(chain))
```

taken from [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) and adapted for use in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use python sets http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html

```
set(yourlist)
```

it will do the trick